# Linux Mint system clock is days ahead after an overnight laptop suspend

Tags: time, ntp

I'm a long-time Ubuntu user, who recently started trying out Linux Mint on a laptop.  This is not a dual-boot setup, Mint is the only OS on the machine.

When I suspend the laptop (i.e. close the screen) for an hour or so, the system clock is still accurate when I open the screen and wake it back up.  However, after an overnight suspend, the clock is wildly wrong.  I could almost understand the clock being stuck in the past, but instead it is usually three or so days in the future.

This is a surprisingly infuriating issue... because I usually don't notice it until after I've done some data entry with an app that relies upon the local clock, and realize that all the data I just entered has corrupted date values.

I have never experienced this issue with any Ubuntu variant before, or with any RedHat variant for that matter.  I've installed "ntp", with default settings since I'm not familiar with its configuration, but that hasn't helped.

Any insights on why a Linux Mint system clock might be thrown days into the future following an overnight laptop suspend?

Comment: What time shows your router? Is the battery of your hardware clock in good shape? Does Mint use systemd?

Answer (score 0):

The source cause of this problem might be unclear. It may be a bad battery (usually a 2032 button cell) in the hardware clock. Could be a problem with systemd-timesyncd daemon to sync clock to a local network ntp server clock. It may be that your router is serving an incorrect ntp time. It needs further investigation.

The quick solution might be to install ntpdate or (better) chrony. The ntp package is not as reliable as it used to be.